# Magento2: Impossible cache clean

Tags: magento2, cache

Impossible clean cache in backend:

```
 1 exception(s):
    Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: is_file() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given in /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php on line 512

    Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: is_file() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given in /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php on line 512
    #0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'is_file() expec...', '/home/czasowe/d...', 512, Array)
    #1 /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php(512): is_file('/home/czasowe/d...')
    #2 /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php(227): Cm_Cache_Backend_File->_cleanNew('matchingTag', Array)
    #3 /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache/Core.php(465): Cm_Cache_Backend_File->clean('matchingTag', Array)
    #4 /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Core.php(98): Zend_Cache_Core->clean('matchingTag', Array)
    #5 /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Frontend/Adapter/Zend.php(79): Magento\Framework\Cache\Core->clean('matchingTag', Array)
    #6 /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Frontend/Decorator/Bare.php(91): Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Adapter\Zend->clean('matchingTag', Array)
    #7 /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Frontend/Decorator/TagScope.php(75): Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Decorator\Bare->clean('matchingTag', Array)
    #8 /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Frontend/Decorator/Bare.php(91): Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Decorator\TagScope->clean('matchingTag', Array)
    #9 /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Frontend/Decorator/Logger.php(47): Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Decorator\Bare->clean('all', Array, 'all')
    #10 /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/Controller/Adminhtml/Cache/FlushSystem.php(27): Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Decorator\Logger->clean()
    #11 /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Backend/Controller/Adminhtml/Cache/FlushSystem/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Cache\FlushSystem->execute()
    #12 /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(107): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Cache\FlushSystem\Interceptor->execute()
    #13 /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(229): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #14 /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #15 /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Cache\FlushSystem\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
    #16 /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Cache\FlushSystem\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #17 /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Cache\FlushSystem\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #18 /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Cache\FlushSystem\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #19 /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Backend/Controller/Adminhtml/Cache/FlushSystem/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Cache\FlushSystem\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)
    #20 /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Cache\FlushSystem\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #21 /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #22 /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
    #23 /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #24 /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
    #25 /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
    #26 /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
    #27 /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
    #28 /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
    #29 {main}
```

log file:

```
[2018-09-02 13:42:36] main.CRITICAL: Cannot gather stats! Warning!stat(): stat failed for /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/pub/static/frontend/Mgs/claue/pl_PL/mage/requirejs/mixins.js {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\FileSystemException(code: 0): Cannot gather stats! Warning!stat(): stat failed for /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/pub/static/frontend/Mgs/claue/pl_PL/mage/requirejs/mixins.js at /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:71)"} []
[2018-09-02 13:43:01] main.CRITICAL: Cannot gather stats! Warning!stat(): stat failed for /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/pl_PL/mage/requirejs/mixins.js {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\FileSystemException(code: 0): Cannot gather stats! Warning!stat(): stat failed for /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/pl_PL/mage/requirejs/mixins.js at /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:71)"} []
[2018-09-02 13:43:01] main.CRITICAL: Cannot gather stats! Warning!stat(): stat failed for /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/pl_PL/mage/requirejs/mixins.js {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\FileSystemException(code: 0): Cannot gather stats! Warning!stat(): stat failed for /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/pl_PL/mage/requirejs/mixins.js at /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:71)"} []
[2018-09-02 13:53:25] main.CRITICAL: The path "/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/var/tmp/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js" cannot be renamed into "/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/pub/static/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js" Warning!rename(/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/var/tmp/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js,/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/pub/static/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js): No such file or directory {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\FileSystemException(code: 0): The path \"/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/var/tmp/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js\" cannot be renamed into \"/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/pub/static/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js\" Warning!rename(/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/var/tmp/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js,/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/pub/static/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js): No such file or directory at /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:298)"} []
[2018-09-02 14:22:45] main.CRITICAL: The path "/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/var/tmp/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js" cannot be renamed into "/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/pub/static/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js" Warning!rename(/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/var/tmp/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js,/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/pub/static/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js): No such file or directory {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\FileSystemException(code: 0): The path \"/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/var/tmp/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js\" cannot be renamed into \"/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/pub/static/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js\" Warning!rename(/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/var/tmp/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js,/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/pub/static/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js): No such file or directory at /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:298)"} []
[2018-09-02 14:28:15] main.CRITICAL: Cannot gather stats! Warning!stat(): stat failed for /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.js {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\FileSystemException(code: 0): Cannot gather stats! Warning!stat(): stat failed for /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.js at /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:71)"} []
[2018-09-02 14:28:40] main.CRITICAL: The file "/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/var/tmp/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js" doesn't exist or not a file {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\FileSystemException(code: 0): The file \"/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/var/tmp/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js\" doesn't exist or not a file at /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Directory/Write.php:70)"} []
[2018-09-02 15:47:49] main.CRITICAL: The file "/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/var/tmp/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js" doesn't exist or not a file {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\FileSystemException(code: 0): The file \"/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/var/tmp/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js\" doesn't exist or not a file at /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Directory/Write.php:70)"} []
[2018-09-02 15:48:11] main.CRITICAL: The file "/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/var/tmp/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js" doesn't exist or not a file {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\FileSystemException(code: 0): The file \"/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/var/tmp/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js\" doesn't exist or not a file at /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Directory/Write.php:70)"} []
[2018-09-02 16:33:14] main.CRITICAL: The file "/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/var/tmp/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js" doesn't exist or not a file {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\FileSystemException(code: 0): The file \"/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/var/tmp/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js\" doesn't exist or not a file at /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Directory/Write.php:70)"} []
[2018-09-02 16:47:23] main.CRITICAL: The file "/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/var/tmp/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js" doesn't exist or not a file {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\FileSystemException(code: 0): The file \"/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/var/tmp/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js\" doesn't exist or not a file at /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Directory/Write.php:70)"} []
[2018-09-02 17:13:25] main.CRITICAL: The path "/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/var/tmp/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js" cannot be renamed into "/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/pub/static/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js" Warning!rename(/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/var/tmp/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js,/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/pub/static/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js): No such file or directory {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\FileSystemException(code: 0): The path \"/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/var/tmp/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js\" cannot be renamed into \"/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/pub/static/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js\" Warning!rename(/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/var/tmp/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js,/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/pub/static/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js): No such file or directory at /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:298)"} []
[2018-09-02 17:20:45] main.CRITICAL: The path "/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/var/tmp/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js" cannot be renamed into "/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/pub/static/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js" Warning!rename(/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/var/tmp/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js,/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/pub/static/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js): No such file or directory {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\FileSystemException(code: 0): The path \"/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/var/tmp/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js\" cannot be renamed into \"/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/pub/static/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js\" Warning!rename(/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/var/tmp/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js,/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/pub/static/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js): No such file or directory at /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:298)"} []
[2018-09-02 17:37:42] main.CRITICAL: The path "/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/var/tmp/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js" cannot be renamed into "/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/pub/static/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js" Warning!rename(/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/var/tmp/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js,/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/pub/static/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js): No such file or directory {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\FileSystemException(code: 0): The path \"/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/var/tmp/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js\" cannot be renamed into \"/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/pub/static/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js\" Warning!rename(/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/var/tmp/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js,/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/pub/static/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js): No such file or directory at /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:298)"} []
[2018-09-02 17:41:48] main.CRITICAL: The file "/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/var/tmp/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js" doesn't exist or not a file {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\FileSystemException(code: 0): The file \"/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/var/tmp/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js\" doesn't exist or not a file at /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Directory/Write.php:70)"} []
[2018-09-02 17:56:28] main.CRITICAL: The file "/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/var/tmp/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js" doesn't exist or not a file {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\FileSystemException(code: 0): The file \"/home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/var/tmp/_cache/merged/dff080226ea3597444c03925cb09364e.js\" doesn't exist or not a file at /home/czasowe/domains/czasowewyprzedaze.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Directory/Write.php:70)"} []
[
```